# SPOJ Prime generator in JAVA

Tags: java

> Input
>
> The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line
>   (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1
>   <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.
>
> Output
>
> For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n,
>   one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.
>
> Example
>
> Input: 2 1 10 3 5
>
> Output: 2 3 5 7
>
> 3 5

I wrote this one:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        long n1=0;
        long n2=0;
        while(i<=n){

            n1  = sc.nextLong();
            n2  = sc.nextLong();
            if(n1==1)
            {
                n1++;
            }
            if((n1-n2)<=100000){

            for(long j=n1;j<=n2;j++){

                int count = 0;

                for(long k=2;k<=j/2;k++){
                    if(j%k==0){
                        count = 1;
                    }
                }
                if(count==0){
                    System.out.println(j);
                }

            }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

It is working fine in my system
But it is showing time exceeded on submission.

Comment: break after `count = 1;`

Comment: I did but not working..